# all strings of upper case with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

This will probably be a quick resolution for someone more adept at regular expressions than myself, but essentially what I am trying to is take a line of a linguistic gloss (like this:)

> E Q that.thing.IN when exist LOC?

and pull out all the parts that are entirely in upper case and put them into an array. I've gotten as far as using:

```
preg_match_all("|[A-Z]|U",$text,$GLOSSES,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

but this makes an array like:

```
E, Q, I, N, L, O, C
```

and what I need is:

```
E, Q, IN, LOC
```

can anyone help? :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use world boundary metasequance `\b` to determine the words as such

the regex would be

```
\b[A-Z]+\b
```

ensures that the regex is bound by word boundary `\b` at both the ends of the uppercase word

```
preg_match_all("\b[A-Z]+\b",$text,$GLOSSES,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

would give output as

```
E, Q, IN, LOC
```